# how to route in nodejs with react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm using front reactjs and backend nodejs. react address is localhost:3000, and node address is localhost:5000. I already set up my proxy at react with node. this porxy setting only works in react js.  but I want to use api server using routing. for example when I type the url "localhost:3000/api/hello", it route to nodejs "localhost:5000/api/hello". is is possible?
here is my nodejs code.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.port || 5000;
const fs = require('fs');
const moment = require('moment');
const data = fs.readFileSync('./database.json');
const config = JSON.parse(data);
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : config.host,
    user: config.user,
    password : config.password,
    port : config.port,
    database : config.database
})

const multer =require('multer');
const upload = multer({dest:'./upload'});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use('/image',express.static('./upload'));


app.get('/api/hello',(req,res)=>{
    res.send({message:"Hello Charles!"});
});


app.listen(port,()=>console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: Rather than do that, why not host both your backend and your frontend on the same port? You can create an `express` app for your frontend, then `app.use(backendApp)`.

Comment: I don't understand this. how can I host frontend and backend with same port?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested you should be using the same port here for serving static assets and serving APIs. Just by adding a few lines in existing code it can be done.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.port || 5000;
const fs = require('fs');
const moment = require('moment');
const data = fs.readFileSync('./database.json');
const config = JSON.parse(data);
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host : config.host,
    user: config.user,
    password : config.password,
    port : config.port,
    database : config.database
})

const multer =require('multer');
const upload = multer({dest:'./upload'});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

app.use('/image',express.static('./upload'));

//  ************All static files will be servered from here.*************** 
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build')));

// *************** You can initialize API's here.***************  
app.get('/api/hello',(req,res)=>{
    res.send({message:"Hello Charles!"});
});

// *************** Fallback if no route is matching, index.html will be returned.*************** 
app.route('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/index.html'))
});

app.listen(port,()=>console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

In the development mode, we can specify in the package.json for proxying requests while the app is run from **npm start**

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```